# How to test master behaviour in a Node.JS cluster?

Tags: node.js, testing

Suppose you are running a cluster in Node.JS and you wish to unit-test it.  For instance, you'd like to make sure that if a worker dies the cluster takes some action, such as forking another worker and possibly some related job.  Or that, under certain conditions, additional workers are spawned.

I suppose that in order to do this one must launch the cluster and have somehow access to its internal state; then (for instance) force workers to get stuck, and check the state after a delay.  If so, how to export the state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to architect your master to return a reference to its cluster object. In your tests, you can kill one of its workers with `cluster.workers[2].kill()`. The worker object also has a reference to the child's process object, which you can use to simulate various conditions. You may have to use a setTimeout to ensure the master has the time to do its thing.

The above methods however still creates forks, which may be undesirable in a testing scenario. Your other option is to use a mocking library (SinonJS et al) to mock out `cluster`'s fork method, and then spy the number of calls it gets. You can simulate worker death by using `cluster.emit('exit')` on the master cluster object.

Note: I'm not sure if this is an issue only with me, but `cluster.emit` always seems to emit twice for me, for some reason.